# MaskedTextBox.Mask not working properly

Tags: c#, .net, textbox, masking, maskedtextbox

I am using `MaskedTextBox` in my code to for a date field.

When I am giving `maskedTextBox1.Mask = "00/00/0000 00:00 AA"` in code,on running the application in my machine it works fine and mask in the `textbox` appears as `[_  _/_ _ _/____ __:__ _  _ _]`

But when i am running the same application in another machine, the mask appears as `[_ _ _-_ _ _-____ __:__ _  _ _]`

How is the `/` replaced by `-`? Is the mask machine dependent, if yes how can we avoid this problem?

Comment: >Another machine means, another system at client location. I debug through the code also, the value assigned to the mask is correct but still it shows '-' instead of '/' on UI.

Comment: I believe it's just user preferences on the target machine. However, I don't know if there is an easy way to force the mask display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be avoided by providing escape character before '/'.
e.x. maskedTextBox1.Mask = @"00\/00\/0000 00:00 AA";
This will force the system to show '/' on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has more to do with application culture 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask.aspx